# How do I trigger a specific job that belongs to a pipeline from another project in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm aware that is possible to trigger another pipeline from another project by adding the below commands in a `gitlab-ci` file:

```
bridge:
  stage: stage_name_here
  trigger: 
    project: path_to_another_project
    branch: branch_name
    strategy: depend
```

The problem is that the config above will trigger all jobs, and I want to trigger only 2 jobs within the pipeline.

Any idea on how to trigger only those 2 specific jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining a variable that needs to be passed by the upstream pipeline that is triggering the downstream pipeline, I simply added the lines below in the jobs that I don't want to run in the downstream pipeline when triggered by another job:

```
except:
    refs:
      - pipelines
```

source:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/index.html#configure-cicd-jobs-to-run-in-triggered-pipelines

Comment: Not suitable for a scenario where there are more triggerable jobs and various upstreams are able to run their own selection of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with rules, only and except keywords in triggered ci file, for example add this to jobs that you want to trigger:

```
except:
  variables:
    - $CI_PROJECT_ID != {{ your main project id }}
```

And for jobs you don't want trigger this:

```
except:
  variables:
    - $CI_PROJECT_ID == {{ your main project id }}
```

Or if you want use rules, add this to jobs you want to run in main project:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_PROJECT_ID == {{ your main project id }}
    when: never
  - when: always
```

Comment: As far as I know, the `$CI_PROJECT_ID` gets the id of the current project, right? (`https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html`). The jobs that I want to trigger and that will have the logic above are in a different project from the project that are triggering those jobs, so the comparison `$CI_PROJECT_ID == {{ your main project id }}` will always be false, right?

Comment: You may just use custom variable flags, eg. IGNORE_JOB_A; define them in the other projects Job - and then drive the job selection based on that. 

Just in case if you are looking for something like reusable/common jobs; you may create templates and then include it in your project gitlab-ci file 
see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html

Comment: I just need to pass the variable from the upstream job to the downstream job in the other project, right? Would this work in the upstream project? 
`variables: CI_PROJECT_ID: $CI_PROJECT_ID`

And then I can use the logic suggest above by @Makariy , using the value of $CI_PROJECT_ID sent from the upstream project?

Comment: @jimmy your downstream pipe starts at the same project and same commit as upstream, so you do't need to pass predefined variables to it

Comment: I choose $CI_PROJECT_ID just for example, you can choose your conditions

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a specific job in the downstream pipeline. What you can do is to pass an env variable into the trigger job:

```
variables:
 ENV: qa1    
child2:
  trigger:
    include: .child-pipeline.yml
    forward:
      yaml_variables: true
```

The above will pass the variable from the trigger job into the downstream job then on the specific downstream job you want to trigger add the following rules:

```
 rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline" && $ENV == "qa1"
    when: always
```

with that rule it will only tigger that job from the list of all jobs in the downstream pipeline.