GITLAB - Multiproject connections (parent-child) , want to trigger a specific job/stage
I have two projects Project A and Project B and have stablished parent-child connections
When a job from parent project triggers it kicks off first stage/job of the child.
But I want to trigger only a specific job.
Project A

Stage A
Job A

Project B

Stage A
Job A
Stage B
Job A
Job B
Job C
Stage C
Job C

Code Snippets
Project A
deploy_parent:
  stage: deploy
  only: ['dev']
  variables:
    env: dev
  script:
    - |
      curl -k --request POST "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/XXXXX/trigger/pipeline?token=$token&variables[TRIGERRED_JOB]=ABC"

Project B
deploy_child:
   stage: deploy
   only:
     variables:
        - $TRIGERRED_JOB == "ABC"
   script:
     - |
     echo "Hello!"

When Project A runs the parent-chid pipeline it triggers Project B (StageA/JobA) but I only want to trigger StageC/JobC
Any leads ?
Thankyou in advance
I have already tried with (except/only/rules) option  also followed this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144258/how-do-i-trigger-a-specific-job-that-belongs-to-a-pipeline-from-another-project
